# File reading from another machine using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I want to read a file from another machine from network using spring boot,i don't need to read from c: directory.

```
public String checkAudioFile(List<AudioTable> addfilename) {
    int count = 0;
    ObjectMapper objMap = new ObjectMapper();
    String jsonMap = null;
    Map<String, Object> audioFileMap = null;
    List<Map<String, Object>> audioFileList = null;
    List<String> notCreatedFileList = null;
    List fileList=null;

    try {
        audioFileList = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
        notCreatedFileList=new ArrayList<String>();
        fileList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < addfilename.size(); i++) {
            File folder = new File("\\\\HostName\\POC\\"+ addfilename.get(i).getAudioFilePath() + "/"
                    + addfilename.get(i).getFileName() + "." + addfilename.get(i).getAudioType());
            System.out.println(folder);
            audioFileMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            if (folder.isFile()) {
                count++;
                audioFileMap.put("fileNameSize", addfilename.size());
                audioFileMap.put("audioCreatedCount", count);
                audioFileMap.put("fileName", folder.getName());
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("File not Found");
                audioFileMap.put("fileNameSize", addfilename.size());
                audioFileMap.put("audioCreatedCount", count);
                notCreatedFileList.add(folder.getName());
            }

            audioFileList.add(audioFileMap);

        }
        fileList.add(notCreatedFileList);
        fileList.add(audioFileList);
        jsonMap = objMap.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(fileList);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonMap;
}
```

i try to connect different directory i can't read a file from that machine, 
anyone can help me.thanks in advanced

Answer (score 0):

You need to make spring boot aware about the machine so will have to define the IP and location of the file.Try with below.

```
URL url = new URL("file://192.168.1.157/home/directoryname/picture.jpg");
Image image = ImageIO.read(url); //read file in case of images
```

NOTE : Don't miss the `file` in the URL.

Comment: I try i can't able to connect,I have file in 'E:' directory folder name POC. file://192.168.1.105/Users/$E/POC/filename  and file://192.168.1.105/$E/POC/filename  is not working.that folder also shared to that machine